# Extend Django base.html in multiple separate sections?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

My **base.html** divides the page into two equal columns.

```
<body>
    <div class="column-left">
    </div>

    <div class="column-right">
    </div>
</body>
```

On **homepage.html**, I would like to extend these columns separately and add some html content to each column e.g. an image.

```
*Extended base.html column-left*
<img src=image_left />



*Extended base.html column-right*
<img src=image_right />
```

Is it possible to extend base.html's columns separately on the homepage.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base.html

```
<body>

    <div class="column-left">
      {% block column_left %}{% endblock %}
    <\div>

    <div class="column-right">
      {% block column_left %}{% endblock %}
    <\div>
</body>
```

Inheritor

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block column_left %}
    <img src=image_left />
{% endblock %}
```

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance).